# X.Single((c) => c is [type]) doesn't work

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, typechecking

I've got a List<Component> collection (Component is a custom class) with **a single element** that inherits from XTYPE.

But for some reason this doesn't work:

```
X = (XTYPE)Components.Single((c) => c is XTYPE);
```

I get an InvalidOperationException with the message "Sequence contains no matching element"
But if I put in a breakpoint at that line and do this it returns `true`:

```
Components[0] is XTYPE
```

Furthermore if I do this it returns `true`:

```
Components[0].GetType().BaseType.BaseType == typeof(XTYPE)
```

Help.

---

**OK**, so I added a few checks into my code...

```
        foreach (Component c in Components)
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().BaseType.BaseType == typeof(Bridge));
        if (Components.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("No components");
        if (!(Components[0].GetType().BaseType.BaseType == typeof(Bridge)))
            throw new Exception("Not bridge.");
```

False gets written to the console, but the type names are the same.
This is probably DLL hell.  And now requires a diff set of information to answer the question.

I think you guys have helped me move toward my solution.

---

Further explanation: the Component in question was instantiated via reflection from a separate instance of the DLL that has XTYPE in it.  So now we've got two XTYPEs but they technically aren't the same type because they've got a diff typehandle.

The debugger wasn't checking in the right context so it thought the types were the same.  But it was wrong.

Comment: It's not working because your caps-lock key is broken.

Comment: What *kind* of "isn't working" ?

Comment: right, touche aakashm.  Let me grab the exact exception.

Comment: Wait, I think I found my problem.  Kill me now.

Comment: Then you should post the solution as an answer so other developers can benefit from it.

Comment: Are you getting InvalidOperationException?

Comment: If you have more than one XTYPE in your collection, Single() is going to throw an exception.

Comment: nope, didn't find my problem.  continue helping.

Comment: also i made my question more clear.  moved stuff out of edits.

Comment: You could put the stuff you're typing in in immediate mode into `Debug.Assert`s and check if that makes a difference. I still think that referring to the wrong `Components` is the most likely problem.

Comment: Your third code sample *can't* work, you probably mean `== typeof(XTYPE)`?

Comment: What is the type of `Components`? What is the relationship between `XTYPE` and `Components` item type?

Comment: What's the compile-time type of `Components`?

Comment: You say "a single element that inherits from XTYPE". But how come `Components[0].GetType() == typeof(XTYPE)` in this case? It doesn't *inherit*, it *is* an `XTYPE`. Or what do you mean? It's hard to answer the question without variable and type definitions when you contradict yourself.

Comment: How about comparing `GetType().BaseType.BaseType.FullName` and `typeof(Bridge).FullName`?

Comment: See above -- explained my DLL hell comment.

Comment: Cool. Can you post this as an accepted answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Component in question was instantiated via reflection from a separate instance of the DLL that has XTYPE in it. So now we've got two XTYPEs but they technically aren't the same type because they've got a diff typehandle.

The debugger wasn't checking in the right context so it thought the types were the same. But it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`Single` throws if more than one element fulfills the condition. If you want only one of them use `First` instead. But since your update states that the error is "Sequence contains no matching element" `First` won't help you.

You could consider using `OfType`. That won't help with your problem, but makes the code a bit nicer. And prevent you from accidentially using a different type in the cast than in the check.

```
XTYPE x=Components.OfType<XTYPE>().Single();
```

Some other possible reasons:

- you're using a different `Components` in immediate mode. So the collection the code is working on is empty, the one you're referring to in immediate mode contains the element
- The collection implementation is broken, i.e. indexer and enumerator are inconsistent. But since you're probably talking about a `Components` implementation from the framework itself that's rather unlikely.
- The type you're casting to is different from the one you're checking
- You did some illegal multi-threading and corrupted some state

Comment: There's only one component of XTYPE in the sequence.  There's actually only ONE component in the sequence.